# Creating Python Packages For Scientific Linux?

Tags: python, linux, redhat

I have installed Scientific Linux in my computer and have created two python script files to create an application.

How to *package* these script files and create an RPM Package for Scientific Linux, thus creating a command line application?

PS: I have done this in Ubuntu quickly, but can't figure out it in Scientific Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tecadmin.net/create-rpm-of-your-own-script-in-centosredhat/ This would help you to create your own rpm for your own scripts.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker